# document.removeChild not working?

Tags: javascript

i am developing a social networking site on start page i am load div elements to an container div having id "feeds" dynamically .I am adding a button which trigger clearHomepage function For that i am using remove child function.
My code scenario .

```
<div id="feedsCon">
<div id="feeds">
//dynamic div container added on page onload

</div>
</div>
```

my javascript function .

```
 clearHomepage(){

  alert("function called"); //for debugging 
  var feeds=document.getElementById('feeds');
  feeds.parentNode.removeChild(feeds);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in tag. You haven't closed the double quotes of `feeds`. Anyway the following code works.

```js
function clearhome(){
 var el = document.getElementById("feeds");
 el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

```html
<div id="feedsCon">
<div id="feeds">
  Test Content
</div>
</div>
<button onclick="clearhome()">Clear</button>
```

Comment: my code worked var      feedsvar=document.getElementById('feeds');
                                      feedsvar.parentNode.removeChild(feeds);

Comment: feedsvar.parentNode.removeChild(id name instead of variable )